# Throws std::out_of_range error while calling substr function ONLY in certain situations

Tags: c++, substr

I am writing a program which throws the error of :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what(): basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 6) > this->size() (which is 0)
```

The piece of code giving this error is:

```
int K;
cin >> K;
string input = "CLICK 0";
for (int op = 0; op < 8; op++)
{
    getline(cin, input);
    cout << input.substr(6, 1);
}
```

While if I just do :

```
int K;
// cin >> K;
string input = "CLICK 0";
for (int op = 0; op < 8; op++)
{
    getline(cin, input);
    cout << input.substr(6, 1);
}
```

it runs perfectly fine.

The user always inputs the value of string 'input' of the form 'CLICK x' so there
is no question of it terminating due to wrong input. (I need to put the value of K instead of 8 in the loop but that's also showing an error so I put 8 for the time being. Also I initialized string to the same form to ensure that it is always of the desired form, but that also didn't solve the problem.)

*The error crops only when I try to input K otherwise it runs normally.*

I referred similar questions but they didn't answered my query.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the first fragment, the first `getline` call retrieves an empty string - the line feed left in the stream after parsing the integer that went into `K`.

Comment: That solved my problem on adding cin.ignore() after cin >> K; Thanks :)